# Pre-filling select tags from array

Tags: php

I've got this array:

```
$profession_type = array(
   'Professional Engineers',
   'Accountants',
   'Insurance Professionals',
   'Attorneys',
   'Certified Hazardous Materials Managers',
   'Safety Professional',
   'Industrial Hygienists',
   'IT Professionals',
   'Human Resource'
);
```

I am display the contents of the array as the options for the select tag:

```
                        <select name="profession_type[]">
                            <option value=""></option>
EOL;
    foreach ($profession_type as $p){
        print "<option value='" . $p . "'>" . $p . "</option>";
    }
print <<<EOL
                        </select>
```

I've never pre-filled a drop down box with dynamic values. The values in `$profession_type` will change frequently (and will eventually be driven from a table in the db), so I can't do hard code it.

EDIT: Sorry my question was unclear.

- The user will select a value from a previous screen (say it's called id) and hit submit.
- Before the HTML is rendered to the screen, PHP makes a stored procedure call based on the `id` they selected.
- The values that the stored procedures returns will prefill the "profession_type[]" form field.
- I would like the `<option value='accountants' selected>Accountants</option>` if the stored procedure returns "Accountants" for the value of "profession_type" based on the id.

Is that more clear? Sorry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well why not just fetch profession_type from the database and populate the dropdown with those professions rather than hard coding them ?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: No suggestions really.  What you have now should work just fine.  You can interpolate the `$p` in the double-quoted string for a little bit better readability, but it's fine as you have it.

Comment: Either you have to hard code it, or read it in from somewhere else (DB, Text File, etc.). If you're asking what you appear to be doing wrong, there's no separation between your PHP and HTML. If you're not, you need to change your question.

Comment: Sorry folks, I didn't word my question correctly. I edited the question.

Comment: Still -- you're on the right track. You just have to learn how to mix the PHP into the HTML files (like stslavik said), then it'll work. Just replace the weird EOL lines with <?php and ?>, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you guys are right. While looping through my `$profession_type` I will need to check it with the values that my stored procedure has produced.  stslavik, could you post as an answer (rather than a comment) so I can award the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
print '<select name="profession_type">';
print '<option value=""></option>';
foreach ($profession_type as $p)
{
    if ($p == $chosen_profession)
        print "<option value='" . $p . "' selected='selected'>" . $p . "</option>";
    else
        print "<option value='" . $p . "'>" . $p . "</option>";
}
print '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes in your .php file:

```
<!-- some HTML here -->

<?php
$profession_type = [result_from_database_query] ?>

<!-- more HTML here -->

<select name="profession_type">
<?php
   foreach ($profession_type as $p){
        print "<option value='" . $p . "'>" . $p . "</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```